# Cannot upgrade Ubuntu Studio 24.04 bcs of unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, updates, dependencies, ubuntu-studio

After an upgrade to

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:Ubuntu Noble Numbat (development branch)
Release: 24.04
Codename:noble
```

apt won't update bcs of unmet dependencies.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfontconfig1 : Depends: fontconfig-config (>= 2.14.2-6ubuntu1)
 libfontconfig1:i386 : Depends: fontconfig-config:i386 (>= 2.14.2-6ubuntu1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've tried:

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/fontconfig-config_2.14.2-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf', which is also in package ubuntustudio-default-settings 22.04.26.3
dpkg-query: package 'fontconfig-config' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
dpkg-query: package 'fontconfig-config' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
dpkg-query: package 'fontconfig-config' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fontconfig-config_2.14.2-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04 (*noble*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *noble* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *noble* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: @BluesBrother I posted this to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontconfig/+bug/2051313 . Please consider subscribing to that thread in case they ask for details to help future users

Comment: @BluesBrother FYI, https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/upgrade-introduction says "Upgrades from one LTS to the next LTS release are only available after the first point release." and the Ubuntu Studio lead said "Upgrades to 24.04 aren't even supported yet and won't be supported until August 2024 (upon release of 24.04.1)" If you wanted to upgrade to 24.04, you needed to do that through each intermediate release

Comment: @DanielT FYI: the `-d` (or to *development*) allows it early; we use it in QA of the upgrade  (*but it's not supported thus you're correct there*)..  You're 100% accurate on Ubuntu Studio upgrades though; it's still *alpha* and it exists primarily for *Quality Assurance* testing, with a number of issues known & tracked by the *developers* (esp. Erich).  Regardless Daniel, THANK YOU for reporting the bug so at least it could be looked at by the appropriate person (Erich).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that 24.04 moved `/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf` out of `ubuntustudio-default-settings` ([before](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/all/ubuntustudio-default-settings/filelist), [after](https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/all/ubuntustudio-default-settings/filelist)) and into [`fontconfig-config`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/all/fontconfig-config/filelist). The `ubuntustudio-default-settings` package needs to be updated first but the maintainers forgot to add an automatic `Conflicts:` line.

You can retry installing the package in the correct order by running `sudo apt install --upgrade ubuntustudio-default-settings`. If that does not work, you need to forcibly reinstall things in the correct order:

```bash
sudo -i

apt update
apt download ubuntustudio-default-settings
apt download fontconfig-config

# Temporarily force-uninstall only ubuntustudio-default-settings
# so that we DON'T uninstall ubuntustudio-desktop
dpkg --force-all -r ubuntustudio-default-settings
dpkg --force-all -i ./fontconfig-config_*
dpkg --force-all -i ./ubuntustudio-default-settings_*

dpkg --configure -a
apt --fix-broken install
apt upgrade
apt dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Both installing and removing attempt to the package gives the same dependency error.

Comment: @BluesBrother I added a more forceful solution that will temporarily override the dependency error. This is so the packages can be installed in the correct order. The dependency enforcement should come back after the `apt --fix-broken install` step.

Comment: Awesome! This solution worked perfectly, thanks a lot.

Comment: @BluesBrother Welcome to AskUbuntu! Here we usually click on the "accept answer" button to thank people

Comment: I did but needs 15 reputation to be counted :/ "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."